# Algebra of dyadic intervals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am struggling with a question on the measure of dyadic intervals in $[0,1]$.

> Let $n\ge0$. We let $\mathscr D_n$ denote the algebra of dyadic intervals in  $[0,1]$ generated by the intervals of the form $I_{n,k}=[\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}]$, where $k=0,1,...,2^n-1$. It is clear that $\mathscr D_{n} \subset \mathscr D_{n+1}$. Define $\mathscr D=\cup_{j=1}^{\infty} \mathscr D_n$. Is it true that for every $n$ there exists $I\in \mathscr D_{n+1}$ such that $m(D\cup I)=\frac{1}{2}m(D)$  for all $D\in \mathscr D_n$?

I think it is true. For instance, since $\mathscr D_{1}$ is the collection of all finite unions and complements of the intervals $I_{1,k}$, $D$ can be one of the following: 
$$\{[0,1],[0,\frac{1}{2}],[\frac{1}{2},1],(0,\frac{1}{2}],(\frac{1}{2},1],\emptyset\}.$$ 
If we set $I= [0,\frac{1}{4}]\cup[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}]$ or $I= [\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}]\cup[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}] $, then for all $D \in \mathscr D_{1}$, we have
$$m(D\cup I)=\frac{1}{2}m(D).$$

And using the same logic, for $D \in\mathscr D_{n}$, we can set $I$ to be
$$I= I_{n+1,1}\cup I_{n+1,3}\cup I_{n+1,5}\cup...\cup I_{n+1,2^{n+1}-1} . $$

Do you think this approach is correct? Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: I think your first script D should have a subscript n, and then there are some related typos after that. Please fix them.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Sorry about the mistakes, my eyes are a bit sore...